# How to make this responsive?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

For one of my sites I have to make this responsive, but I don't know how.
I'm struggling with the height of the container div.
Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="vak1"></div>
    <div class="vak2"></div>
    <div class="vak3"></div>
    <div class="vak4"></div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    position: relative;
    height: 456px;
    width: 742px;
    top: 15%;
}
.vak1 {
    width: 344px;
    height: 216px;
    background-color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    top: 65px;    
    left: 0px;
    float:left;
}
.vak2 {
    width: 230px;
    height: 129px;
    background-color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    top: 298px;
    left: 114px;
    float:left;
}
.vak3 {
    width: 305px;
    height: 211px;
    background-color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 73px;
    float:left;

}
.vak4 {
    width: 380px;
    height: 225px;
    background-color: #666;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0px;
    float:left;

}
```

What is the best way to do this, to make it complete responsive?

Comment: Your struggling with the height? Why are all the widths in pixels? It is a bad idea to use pixels if you are going to make something responsive.

Comment: Read http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design/ or search you will find good articles, basic of responsive is using % or em for defining container width height

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb8CF/)**

But I' not sure if it's a good idea to keep this structure for small screen devices.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="cont">
    <div class="vak1"></div>
    <div class="vak2"></div>
</div>
<div class="cont">
    <div class="vak3"></div>
    <div class="vak4"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

**[Version 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb8CF/1/)** Seems like a better design for small screen